# rosdep-install and rgbdslam_v2 problem

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
i have git cloned rgbdslam_v2 package on my ros workspace as instructed here: https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2

but when i try to execute "rosdep install rgbdslam_v2" i get following error:

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rgbdslam_v2
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

i am using ros indigo.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223140/rosdep-install-and-rgbdslam_v2-problem/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two things to mention here,

1. The package name is `rgbdslam`, not `rgbdslam_v2`. If you look in the launch files this is how it is referred to. So try running `rosdep install rgbdslam`.
2. Based on the error output from Rosdep, it doesn't look like you have a catkin workspace setup. Did you clone it into /opt/ros/indigo/share? You should setup a catkin workspace as per the tutorials, http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials, clone RGBDSLAM_V2 into there, then you can execute `catkin_make` to build the package.

Also, I've posted this same response in you previous question, http://answers.ros.org/question/223093/ros-packages-for-rgbd-slam-with-kinect/, but I would suggest not repeating the same question in two separate posts. Just stick to one, and if you find the responses helpful mark it as such. That way other users have less posts to look through when looking for answers.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2015-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0